# YouTube video auto play suddenly stops working in iOS 7.0.4

Tags: javascript, ios7, youtube-api, autoplay

My app plays YouTube videos in a UIWebView using the code provided by Google in the "Getting Started" section of [this page.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)  This code uses JavaScript to make the video start playing immediately after it is loaded, without the user having to tap the red play button.  As of a few days ago, it suddenly stopped working.  Now it loads the video and displays the play button, requiring the user to tap it to play.

I also created an HTML document with the exact code, and opened it in Safari on iOS 7, and the same thing happens.

Any thoughts on how to fix this, or achieve the same behavior in a different way?

**UPDATE**

My code just started working again.  No changes on my end, I'm certain.  Perhaps there was a bug in the YouTube player itself?  I do not think Apple updated anything.

Answer (score 0):

Possible you're being bit by this bug?

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5204

There are some workarounds there which you may try to see if it solves your issue.